# Getting data from xml in android

Tags: android, xml

I am working on android application. In my app I got the xml data response from server and stored it in a string. Now I need to get each value of that xml and display in a dropdown. How can I do that?

My xml data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<root>
<status>first<status>
<description>very good</description>
<Firstnames>
<name>CoderzHeaven</name>
<name>Android</name>
<name>iphone</name>
</Firstnames>
<SecondNames>
 <name>Google</name>
 <name>Android</name>
</SecondNames>
</root>
```

I am getting the above mentioned xml data from server. Now I need to display that in listview. How can I get those values using xmlparser. I tried with different examples but it didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an extra class and parametrize your adapter with objects of this class, an example data model would look like:

```
  public class DataClass {

private String status, description;
private ArrayList<String> fnames, lnames;

public DataClass() {
    fnames = new ArrayList<String>();
    lnames = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

    public ArrayList<String> getFnames() {
    return fnames;
}

public ArrayList<String> getLnames() {
    return lnames;
}
}
```

As for the XML parser, there are literally tons of examples, you're definitely in advantage if you can use search. Just to give you a staring point, tutorials [one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm), [two](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidXML/article.html), [three](http://androidexample.com/XML_Parsing_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=69&aaid=94), [four](http://theopentutorials.com/tag/android-xml-parser-example/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it if the xml is inside of your apps assets folder.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    InputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("data.xml");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DocumentBuilder builder = null;
    try {
        builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Document doc = null;
    if (builder == null) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Builder is empty.");
        return;
    }
    try {
        doc = builder.parse(input);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (doc == null) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Document is empty.");
        return;
    }

    // Get Firstnames element
    Element firstNames = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("Firstnames").item(0);
    // Get name nodes from Firstnames
    NodeList nameNodes = firstNames.getElementsByTagName("name");
    // Get count of names inside of Firstnames
    int cChildren = nameNodes.getLength();
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(cChildren);
    for (int i=0; i<cChildren; i++) {
        names.add(nameNodes.item(i).getTextContent());
        Log.d("TAG","Name: "+names.get(i));
    }

    // Do same with SecondNames
}
```